# How to use ContinuationWidth from the start of the conditional, not start of function call in clang-format?

Tags: clang-format

Here the problematic code snippet:

```c
int open_server_socket(Config config) {
    if (setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optVal,
                sizeof(optVal)) < 0) { // THIS LINE
        socket_error();
    }
}
```

I need the indicated line to be indented by 12 spaces instead of 16, so it looks like this:

```c
int open_server_socket(Config config) {
    if (setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optVal,
            sizeof(optVal)) < 0) { // THIS LINE
        socket_error();
    }
}
```

My `.clang-format` looks like this:

```yaml
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
EscapedNewlineAlignmentStyle: Left
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignOperands: DontAlign
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
ColumnLimit: 79
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
OperandAlignmentStyle: DontAlign
```

My best attempt at getting this particular configuration was to use the combination of `AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign` and `ContinuationIndentWidth: 8`, but in this case that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Edit: Further context here from my course's style guide to demonstrate why `ContinuationWidth` must be 8:

```c
if (expressionA || expressionB || expressionC || expressionD || 
        expressionE || expressionF) {
//345678
    /* code goes here − indented by 4 spaces */
    ...
    printf("A very long string can be broken like "
            "this");
  //12345678
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```yaml
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
```

`ContinuationIndentWidth` is the indentation relative to the default indentation on this line. You want 4 chars (not 8) extra.

Comment: This does what I specified in the question yes, but it affects the continuation width all over my files. I need the continuation width to be 8 for everything else, not 4.

Comment: I've added a snippet from the style guide in my question to demonstrate this requirement

Comment: Your course's style? The tutor should provide you with the required with a config. If it does not, I would consider going to another teacher.

Comment: They didn't provide any formatting config files. Only a pdf style sheet so I have been manually putting together a clang format config to make my life easier. This is the ONLY thing that it does incorrectly (apart form naming scheme)